# Flextable Word output - How to display each table on a different page?

Tags: r, ms-word, flextable

I have several tables that I want to save in a Word document.

Specifically, I would like to display each table on a different page.

How can I do this?

```
library(flextable)
head(mtcars)
FT=flextable(head(mtcars))
save_as_docx(values=list(FT,FT),path="result.docx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

officer is a possible solution:

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)
head(mtcars)
FT=flextable(head(mtcars))
read_docx() |> 
  body_add_flextable(FT) |> 
  body_add_break() |> 
  body_add_flextable(FT) |> 
  body_add_break() |> 
  print(target="result.docx")
```